# Limit Rows in ETL Without Date Column for Cue

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, etl

We have two large tables (Clients and Contacts) which undergo an ETL process every night, being inserted into a single "People" table in the data warehouse. This table is used in many places and cannot be significantly altered without a lot of work.

The source tables are populated by third party software; we used to assume that we could identify the rows that had been updated since last night by using the "UpdateDate" column in each, but more recently identified some rows that were not touched by the ETL, as the "UpdateDate" column was not behaving as we had thought; the software company do not see this as a bug, so we have to live with this fact.

As a result, we now take *all source rows*, transformed into a temp staging table and then Merge that into the data warehouse, using the Merge to identify any changed values. We have noticed that this process is taking too long on some days and would like to limit the number of rows that the ETL process looks at, as we believe that the reason for the hold-up is the principally the sheer volume of data that is examined and stored on the temp database. We can see no way to look purely at the source data and identify when each row last changed.

Here is a simplified pseudocode of the ETL stored procedure, although what the procedure actually does is not really relevant to the question (included just in case you disagree with me!)

```
CREATE #TempTable (ClientOrContact BIT NOT NULL, Id INT NOT NULL, [Some_Other_Columns])

INSERT #TempTable
SELECT 1 AS ClientOrContact, C.Id, [SomeColumns] FROM
    (SELECT [SomeColumns]
     FROM Source_ClientsTable C
     JOIN FieldsTable F JOIN [SomeOtherTables])
    PIVOT (MAX(F.FieldValue) FOR F.FieldName IN ([SomeFieldNames]));

INSERT #TempTable
SELECT 0 AS ClientOrContact, C.Id, [SomeColumns] FROM
    (SELECT [SomeColumns]
     FROM Source_ContactsTable C
     JOIN FieldsTable F JOIN [SomeOtherTables])
    PIVOT (MAX(F.FieldValue) FOR F.FieldName IN ([SomeFieldNames]));

ALTER #TempTable ADD PRIMARY KEY (ClientOrContact, Id);

MERGE Target_PeopleTable AS Tgt
USING (SELECT [SomeColumns] FROM #TempTable JOIN [SomeOtherTables]) AS Src
    ON Tgt.ClientOrContact = Src.ClientOrContact AND Tgt.Id = Src.Id

WHEN MATCHED AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT Tgt.* INTERSECT SELECT Src.*)
    THEN UPDATE SET ([All_NonKeyTargetColumns] = [All_NonKeySourceColumns])

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target THEN INSERT [All_TargetColumns] VALUES [All_SourceColumns]
OUTPUT $Action INTO @Changes;

RETURN COUNT(*) FROM @Changes;
GO
```

The source tables have about 1.5M rows each, but each day only a relatively small number of rows are inserted or updated (never deleted). There are about 50 columns in each table, of those, about 40 columns can have changed values each night. Most columns are VARCHAR and each table contains an independent incremental primary key column. We can add indexes to the source tables, but not alter them in any other way (They have already been indexed by a predecessor) The source tables and target table are on the same server, but different databases. **Edit:** The Target Table has a composite primary key on the `ClientOrContact` and `Id` columns, matching that shown on the temp table in the script above.

So, my question is this - please could you suggest any general possible strategies that might be useful to limit the number of rows we look at or copy across each night? If we only touched the rows that we needed to each night, we would be touching less than 1% of the data we do at the moment...

Comment: If the Id values in the source tables are setup correctly and incremental, you could store the values as an external reference in the destination table and make your delta update only look for Id values in the source table `> MAX(ExternalId)` in the destination. I guess you may need 2 reference columns though being that you have 2 sources though.

Comment: I believe with ETL you mean SSIS; dealing with large number of rows is very well taken care by SSIS because of Non blocking transformation. The same operation in TSQL may take significant amount of time. Is there any way to to identify any natural key (it may increase load efficiency for type 1 dimension)

Comment: @Tanner, If I understand you correctly, that would work for the new rows, but not for those that need updating; we would still need to look at nearly all the rows, and the insert could not be much faster than the primary key comparison performed by the merge in the `WHEN NOT MATCHED` clause

Comment: @AnujTripathi I could move the ETL for this table into an SSIS, but I have always believed that SQL will do the job more swiftly than SSIS; maybe this is not true in all cases?

Comment: @HighPlainsGrifter SSIS does a pretty good job when you are using asynchronous transformation over large amount of data. I recommend you to identify natural key (if possible) and separate insert and update logic.

Comment: both the source tables have a natural primary key, but the problem I am having is that there are an unknown number of rows that need updating - I do not understand how using the primary key will identify these faster than the sql currently is (which also uses the primary keys where possible). Only about 1000 rows are updated each night; replacing the sql merge with a merge join or lookup transformation in SSIS will surely not be so very much faster, compared to improving the ability to identify the rows that should be updated more efficiently?

Comment: @HighPlainsGrifter can you update with the schema definitions for the source Clients and Contacts tables?

Comment: @AlanMacdonald I'm not sure... do you mean using `TRANSFER` or similar to copy the tables from one database schema to another?

Comment: @HighPlainsGrifter no I just mean can we see what columns are in those sources tables in order to try and work out a solution.  By update I meant update the question!

Comment: @AlanMacdonald Ah - that makes much more sense! :) If you are sure... It'll be another ~100 lines of the question; would it be enough to know that all columns are `NVARCHAR`,`VARCHAR`,`INT`,`DATETIME` and `DECIMAL`, with the string columns having a scale between 50 and 250; and that there are about 50 columns in each table, with an `IDENTITY` column holding a primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you try the following suggestion, just one thing to check is that the Target_PeopleTable has an index or primary key on the id column.  It probably does but without schema information to verify I am making no assumptions and this might speed up the merge stage.

As you've identified if you could somehow limit the records in TempTable to just the changed rows then this could offer a performance win for the actual MERGE statement (depending on how expensive determining just the changed rows is).

As a general strategy I would consider some kind of checksum to try and identify the changed records only.  The [T-SQL Checksum function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189788.aspx) could be used to calculate a check sum across the required columns by specifying the columns as a comma separated list to that function or there are actual column types available for this such as Binary_Checksum.

Since you cannot change the source schema you would have to maintain a list of record ids and associated checksums in your target database so that you can readily compare the source checksums to the target checksums from the last run in order to identify a difference.

You can then only insert into the Temp table where there is a checksum difference between the target and source or the id does not exist in the target db.

This might just be moving the performance problem to the temp insert part but I think it's worth a try.

Comment: This looks like the solution to me - thanks for the advice. I have made a couple of tables; one holding client ids and checksums and the other contact ids and checksums, and I will check for differences each evening. I have had to be careful with my transactions so I rollback the checksum update if the final merge fails, meaning only merged records will show; I ran this last night as part of the automated ETL (test version) and it seems to work perfectly, reducing the time by about a factor of 1000!

Comment: @HighPlainsGrifter no problem.  I'm glad to have helped.  I'm surprised it's so much faster.  I'll need to remember this one in case i end up in a similar scenario!

Comment: I should be more precise actually; the five minute limit has passed to edit the comment, the first time I ran the script, it thought there was nothing to update as the checksums were populated from the source tables and there had been no movement since; only this morning was I actually in a position where any differences were identified. The time went from about 9,000 seconds to about 30 seconds when there were rows to update, which is impressive, but not quite 1K times as fast!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered triggers? I avoid them like the plague, but they really are the solution to some problems.

Put an INSERT/UPDATE [/DELETE?] trigger on your two source tables. Program it such that when rows are added or updated, the trigger will log the IDs of these rows in a (you'll have to create this) audit table, where that table would contain the ID, the type of change (update or insert – and delete, if you have to worry about those) and when the change was made. When you run ETL, join this list of “to be merged” items with the source tables. When you’re done, delete the table and it’s reset for the next run. (Use the “added on” datetime column to make sure you don’t delete rows that may have been added while you were running ETL.)

There’s lots of details behind proper use and implementation, but overall this idea should do what you need.

Comment: Unfortunately, the source database cannot be altered so as to include triggers, for fear of having an unacceptable impact on the live software performance for our staff; thanks for the suggestion, however - I see that this is a sensible suggestion and would have been a viable solution had we been able to affect the source database in this way.